# How to create objects using new operator and use them using for loop

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
class account \\simple class
{
    int accno;
    int balance;
    public:
    account()
    {
        cout<<"Enter Account No : ";
        cin>>accno;
        cout<<"Enter Balance : ";
        cin>>balance;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"\n" <<accno<<"\t"<<balance;
    }
};
void main()
{
    int n;
    clrscr();
    cout<<"Enter no of Accounts : ";
    cin>>n;
    account *ob = new account[n]; \\is this statement work..??
    cout<<"\n Account No \t Balance \n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        ob[i]->display(); \\  how to access all object's display function.
    }
    delete ob; 
    getch();
}
```

// in ob[i]-> display() i got an error .. pointer to structure required on left side
// but if i write code  ob->display() then only first record is display n times. plz provide any solution guys...thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the i'th element, it is no longer a pointer. So

```
ob[i].display();
```

Comment: ..thnks bro..can u plz tell me the overall program is correct  concept wise . (Dynamic memory allocation and dealocation)..

Comment: The overall concept is correct but for one thing: if you "new account[n];", you have to call "delete [] ob;" instead of "delete ob;". But I would suggest two things. First of all, in your case using an std::vector is better. It will allocate memory dynamically for you (e.g. to expand vector size) so there is no need for you to call the new operator explicitly. Secondly, if you really need to deal with pointers, try to use a smart pointer such as std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr. This way you don't need to worry about calling the delete operator explicitly.